# Tensorflow 1.4 Keras issue with respect to model_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-2

I have a model function which accepts Features, targets and mode but when I add tf.keras layers I'm currently getting Exception pred must be a Tensor, a Variable, or a Python bool.

But, When I run the same code with out using tf.keras but directly from keras(i.e. from keras.layers), It's working.

Code :

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1)
else:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)

input_feature = features['x']
table = lookup.index_table_from_file(vocabulary_file='vocab.txt', num_oov_buckets=1, default_value=-1)
text = tf.squeeze(input_feature, [1])
words = tf.string_split(text)
densewords = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(words, default_value=PADWORD)
numbers = table.lookup(densewords)
padding = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, MAX_FEATURES]])
padded = tf.pad(numbers, padding)
sliced = tf.slice(padded, [0, 0], [-1, MAX_FEATURES])
print('words_sliced={}'.format(words))

#embeds = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_FEATURES, 50, input_length=MAX_FEATURES)(sliced)
embeds = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(sliced, vocab_size=MAX_FEATURES, embed_dim=50)
print('words_embed={}'.format(embeds))

f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(embeds)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(f1)
# f1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dims)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(f1)
f1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(f1)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(11)(f1)

predictions_dict = {
    'class': tf.argmax(logits, 1),
    'prob': tf.nn.softmax(logits)
}

prediction_output = tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
                                                       "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits,
                                                                                      name="softmax_tensor")})

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions_dict, export_outputs={
        tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: prediction_output
    })

# one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=11)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits=logits)

if mode == tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss, tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), optimizer='Adam',
                                               learning_rate=0.001)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

eval_metrics_ops = {
    'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions_dict['class'])
}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics_ops)
```

When I execute the above script I'm getting an exception
**TypeError: pred must be a Tensor, a Variable, or a Python bool.**

But also when I used keras(from keras) directly without tf.keras it's working. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: I can't help meaningfully with info provided. Maybe you can take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/estimator/model_to_estimator.

Comment: What part you didn't understand @iga

Comment: Using tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True) or tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False) seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)
else:
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(False)
```

Setting learning_phase = True or False is solving the problem.